# Avoid multiple server calls, "self-filtering" JqueryUI autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Consider "Method A: no ajax":

```
$(function() {
    var emails = [
        "john@beatles.com",
        "george@beatles.com",
        "paul@beatles.com",
        "ringo@beatles.com"
    ];

    $( "#invitees" ).autocomplete({
          source:emails
    });
});
```

This is given a relatively small, "unfiltered" array.  The autocomplete function filters it for you as you type.  I want to fetch this data once, thereby only requiring one call to the database.

Consider "Method B: 'internal' URL:

```
$( "#invitees" ).autocomplete({
    source:"/api/get/users"
});
```

This does not work as I expect it to.  No matter what I type, the entire list is always there.  Now, after research reading the docs, other S/O questions, and every example I can find- they usually conclude with something like this:

> "Data should be filtered server side. The autocomplete widget adds the **term** parameter to the url, so the resulting url is something like: **`/search.php?term=whatityped`**

I can handle that, but that's not totally happening in "Method A", is it?  For larger data sets, I get it: no need to pre-load 100,000 results.  But in this case, I want the ability to run one query and be done with it.  That way if a mobile user is standing in the desert with "one bar" of service, his phone won't lock up while the server repeatedly requests new data every time he types a letter, right?

When the request goes to the internal URL:'/api/get/users'... here's the relevant part of the PHP code:

```
function get($className,$param1="all",$param2=""){
    //above parameters will be refactored...
    $stmt=$this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users');
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    echo json_encode($this->data);
}
```

That function returns:

```
["john@beatles.com","george@beatles.com","paul@beatles.com","ringo@beatles.com"]
```

So again, If I explicitly do this, the filtering works:

```
    var emails = [
        "john@beatles.com",
        "george@beatles.com",
        "paul@beatles.com",
        "ringo@beatles.com"
    ];

    $( "#invitees" ).autocomplete({
          source:emails
    });
```

but this does not:

```
$( "#invitees" ).autocomplete({
    source:"/api/get/users"
});
```

What am I missing here?

PS: Here is an unpolished attempt at method C, by the way- "ajax callback":
(Note: it's meant to accept an associative array from PHP, but the point is that it also does not "self-filter")

```
$( "#invitees" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/api/get/users",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                maxRows:5, // ? does not work
                //name_startsWith: request.term // ? does not work
            },
            error: function(xhr,status){
                alert(status);
            },
            success: function (data){
                // alert(data);
                response($.map(data,function (item){
                    return{
                        label: item.username,
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
//ensures autocomplete is not set to "off"
$('input[name=invitees]').attr('autocomplete','on');
```

For completeness, here's My HTML:

```
<label for="invitees">Invite by email: </label>
<input id="invitees" name="invitees"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the autocomplete function inside a callback function and pass the return data into that.

An example:

```
        $.getJSON('/myJSONdata', function(data) { 
             $( "#input_field" ).autocomplete({
            source: data
            });
        });
```

This will assign the autocomplete function to the desired fields after the callback is complete and the data would be assigned just as if it were plain text written into the function.

The autocomplete function obviously won't work until the callback completes successfully so that is something that you might want to keep in mind.